# algorithm calendar objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, calendar

I want to create a calendar that will display months and days. I don't want to use API or libraries. I want to figure out algorithm how to create calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fast way to do this is calculate the number of days for a month and then write a routine that graphically display the day like the calendar app.

You can use a routine that show a `UIButton` for every day and display its as a virtual grid.
In every row you should show 7 days (from Sunday to Saturday) and then go on the next row to show the following days.